# Get current execution metrics from sys.dm_exec_sessions

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2019, metrics, performance-counters

I've got a pretty complex batch processing procedure that takes hours to run on real data. I've found that some CPU and I/O counters are stored in the `master.sys.dm_exec_sessions` table, and so thought that maybe I can use them to measure which parts of the procedure are taking most resources. However, it seems that repeatedly querying this table within a single procedure always returns the same values.

I know I can trigger update of these statistics by issuing the `GO` statement, but of course it is not possible to do that inside a procedure. Are there any other ways to read these counters that would make sure they are up to date?

MWE:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.MineBitcoins @Prefix INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @It INT = 0
    WHILE COALESCE(TRY_CAST(LEFT(HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CONVERT(VARCHAR, @It))), @Prefix) AS INT), 1) <> 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT @It
        SET @It = @It + 1
    END
    SELECT @It
END
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.MeasureTimeOfAStupidQuery @Prefix INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT cpu_time, reads, logical_reads, writes FROM master.sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @@SPID
    EXEC dbo.MineBitcoins @Prefix
    SELECT cpu_time, reads, logical_reads, writes FROM master.sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @@SPID
END
GO

EXEC dbo.MeasureTimeOfAStupidQuery @Prefix = 3
```

(it takes about 30 seconds on my test database instance).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, we're already collecting wallclock time this way across most of our database code, adding CPU and I/O metrics this way would be way simpler than writing a separate piece of code that would monitor these procedures externally, or attempt to correlate query store information with specific executions.

Comment: Yeah, it's not about a single specific query, it's about many different stored procedures with callstacks of several layers. I'm trying to deal with a lot of legacy business logic and metrics at levels of specific queries or stored procedures won't give me the insight I seek.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like session statistics just can't be updated often enough. However, request statistics are, and for the purpose of the MWE posted in this question (and my actual use case) will work as expected. We should therefore be able to receive up-to-date statistics by querying `sys.dm_exec_requests` as follows:

```
SELECT cpu_time, reads, logical_reads, writes
FROM master.sys.dm_exec_requests
WHERE session_id = @@SPID AND request_id = CURRENT_REQUEST_ID()
```

Comment: The master.sys.dm_exec_sessions metric values update by batch.  That's okay in a client application measuring between batches.  The procedure is in one batch, so master.sys.dm_exec_requests is your only option within the batch.  In the batch, the request will always be the parent request (e.g., before or after query execution).  CURRENT_REQUEST_ID() is required to support MARS.  A metric should measure twice and take a difference.